# Angular prevent multiple token refresh on asynchronous requests

Tags: javascript, angular, rxjs

All my http requests go through the custom **HttpService**. This service refreshes the token when it's expired before sending the request.

It works fine but it refreshes the token multiple times if the loaded page has multiple http requests. For example, if the page has 10 requests through the services, this means 10 times token refresh.

I've tried to describe this by sample code:

**loaded page and used services**

```
export class Page1 implements OnInit {
    constructor(
        private service1: Service1,
        private service2: Service2
    ) { }

    ngOnInit() {
        this.service1.getData...
        this.service2.getData...        
    }   
}

@Injectable()
export class Service1 {
    constructor(
        private httpService: HttpService
    ) {}

    getData(): Observable<any> {
        return this.httpService.get(.....)
            .map((response: Response) => {
                return response.json();
            });
    }
}
@Injectable()
export class Service2 {
    constructor(
        private httpService: HttpService,
        private service1: Service1
    ) {}

    getData(): Observable<any> {
        return this.httpService.get(.....)
            .map((res: Response) => res.json().response)
            .flatMap((newItem: Item) => {
                    this.service1.getData(...)
            });
    }
}
```

**custom http service**

```
@Injectable()
export class HttpService extends Http {

    constructor (backend: XHRBackend, options: RequestOptions) {
        .............
    }

    request(url: string|Request, options?: RequestOptionsArgs): Observable<Response> {

        ................

        if(tokenNotExpired('access_token')){ // if token is NOT expired

            return super.request(url, options);

        }else{  // if token is expired

            return this.updateToken()
                .flatMap((result: boolean) => {
                    return this.request(url, options);  
            });
        }
    }

    updateToken(): Observable<boolean> {

        // set the new token
        .....

    }
}
```

How can I perevent the token refresh per request by setting these requests in que and send them only when the new token is ready?

*Note: I don't know if it's matter but the service requests can be combined by `flatMap` or `forkJoin`....*

**Update 1**

I've updated my code according to ***@bviale***'s answer.

```
request(url: string|Request, options?: RequestOptionsArgs): Observable<Response> {

    ................

    if(tokenNotExpired('access_token')){ // if token is NOT expired

        return super.request(url, options);

    } else {  // if token is expired

        // There is already a call to updateToken() in progress,
        // wait for it to finish then process the request
        if (this.updateTokenPromise) {
            return Observable.fromPromise(return this.updateTokenPromise.then(() => {
                return this.request(url, options);  
            }));
        }
        // Start to call updateToken(), then resolve the promise
        else {
            this.updateTokenPromise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
                this.updateToken().toPromise()
                    .then((result: boolean) => {
                        resolve(result);
                    });
            });

            return Observable.fromPromise(return this.updateTokenPromise.then(() => {
                return this.request(url, options);
            }));
        }
    }
}
```

My updated `request()` method perfectly stops the requests, invokes the `updateToken()` only one time, gets the token, and then calls the requests but for each request I get the following error now:

[image]

I've noticed that the service calls returns the following **response** which ofcourse will cause `e.json is not a function` exception:

```
Object { _isScalar: false, source: Object, operator: Object }
```

I think this is also something I need to cast?

Answer (score 0):

You can create your own Promise when you call `updateToken()` like this :

```
@Injectable()
export class HttpService extends Http {

    private updateTokenPromise: Promise<any>;

    constructor (backend: XHRBackend, options: RequestOptions) {
        .............
    }

    request(url: string|Request, options?: RequestOptionsArgs): Observable<Response> {

        ................

        if(tokenNotExpired('access_token')){ // if token is NOT expired

            return super.request(url, options);

        } else {  // if token is expired

            // There is already a call to updateToken() in progress,
            // wait for it to finish then process the request
            if (this.updateTokenPromise) {
                return this.updateTokenPromise.then(() => {
                    return this.request(url, options);  
                });
            }
            // Start to call updateToken(), then resolve the promise
            else {
                this.updateTokenPromise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
                    this.updateToken()
                        .then((result: boolean) => {
                            resolve(result);
                        });
                });

                return this.updateTokenPromise.then(() => {
                    return this.request(url, options);
                });
            }
        }
    }

    updateToken(): Observable<boolean> {

        // set the new token
        .....

    }
}
```

This way you won't have multiple parallel calls of `updateToken()`

Comment: first time it gave error as `Type 'Promise<any>' is not assignable to type 'Observable<Response>'`. After removing `Observable` return types from `request()` and `updateToken()` it didn't compile because of `then` where used for `resolve(result);`. I've removed it also but after that it failed with the error `this.httpService.get(...).map is not a function in the updateToken()` when the token expired. I guess `Promise` doesn't fit very well:(

Comment: I could manage to get rid off these errors by properly castings between `Promise` and `Observable` but now it gives an another error. Please check my updated question..